# js/jquery homemade slider script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a jQuery slider script I created. This problem comes when I have my page open in my browser for a long time: the slider accelerates.

Here is my JS code :

```
function intervalTrigger() {
        return window.setInterval(function()
            {
                $("#sliderControl ul li.currentSlideControl").removeClass("currentSlideControl");
                $("#sliderControl ul li:eq("+nextSlide+")").addClass("currentSlideControl");

                $("#topSlider ul.slider li.currentSlide").fadeTo(1500, 0).removeClass("currentSlide");
                $("#topSlider ul.slider li:eq("+nextSlide+")").fadeTo(1500, 1.0).addClass("currentSlide");
                nextSlide = ( (nextSlide+1) < nbSlides ) ? nextSlide+1 : 0;

            }, 5000);
        }
    var id = intervalTrigger();
```

As you can see, the interval between each slide is 5 seconds, but if I have the page open for a long time, the slider accelerates and slides go very fast.

Someone tells me that I have to unbind the interval, butI don't know how to do that. :/

Can someone help me?

PS: Sorry for my bad English. :(

Comment: Do you run this script in $(document).ready() construction?

Comment: @GlenSwift what's the link between your comment and the OP;s problem..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I guess script may begin to work before slider image nodes are loaded

Comment: Could yo provide a jsfiddle or something to replicate the problem?
BTW Where the vars `nextSlide` and `nbSlides` are?

Comment: fade transition is an asynchronous animation. Maybe you're nextSlide change more faster and delay was create between transition and slide selection ...

Comment: are you sure this function is being called just once in your code?

Comment: @ThibaultBach I don't think so. Fade operation is asynchronous but the js lines to execute not. First the fadeto is invoked and then nextSlide increments. Sure that nextSlide is incremented before fadeTo finish the animation but that has no real implication on OP's code. I bet for pumpkinzzz suggestion that the interval is called more than once.